# How to place bet via Pinnacle API in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, xmlhttprequest

How does placing bet request from C# for Pinnacle API looks like?

Could someone help with small example?

http://www.pinnacle.com/en/api/manual  - this is pinnacle api documentation

From that documentation without problems I can get for example all teams with totals and other odds or I can get team names.

Here is code example for getting all odds for some type of sport via C# and pinnacle API:

```
/// <summary>
    /// This function get events with their totals
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetAllTotalsAsync(string userLogin, string userPass)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/odds?sportid=" + (int)_sportType);
        string credentials = $"{userLogin}:{userPass}";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        string authorization = String.Concat("Basic ", base64);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        return (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Later from HttpWebResponse we can get JSON output

`var totalResp = await GetAllTotalsAsync(userLogin, userPass).ConfigureAwait(false);
 var sportEvents = (JsonObject)JsonValue.Load(totalResp.GetResponseStream());`

Here in sportEvents we have our JSON with all data.

So, can anyone help me with placing some bets via Pinnacle API by using C# laguage???